# What does mean two points and a class after args: def func(value:str)

Tags: python, parameter-passing

I don't understand what the `arg: str` means

```
def hello(arg: str):
    print(type(arg))
    print('do stuff!', arg)


hello('something')
```

I thought it was specifing a type, but I tried to call hello, and I haven't got any exception. I've tried to call `hello` with an `int`, no error.

I've done a few test, but I haven't come up with anything...

Any idea about what this is doing?

Matt

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski It might be a different question because it's asking about argument type-hinting specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct `def hello(arg: str):` does specify a type for the argument. But in Python, it only provides type-hinting. This means that you can theoretically pass any type of instance to the function. Type-hinting is useful for development and for IDEs because it can help the program notify you if you're passing unexpected arguments to a function.

Extra note, these type-hints are stored in the function under `__annotations__`:

```
In [1]: def f(arg: int):
   ...:     return arg
   ...: 

In [2]: f.__annotations__
Out[2]: {'arg': int}
```

Comment: So, it's only to help the dev, python doesn't give a damn if it's not the right type...

Comment: @math2001 Precisely. Your programs will execute with or without type-hinting.